# How to put both customview and linearlayout in same xml file

Tags: android-layout, textview, android

my problem is ,i am using one custom-view in my XML file ,that same XML file also contain other component such as text-view ,image-buttons,

that custom-view contains the images ,that i want on background

but it is blocking my whole layout (other components)

and i can see only custom-view

following is my code

```
 <FrameLayout 
 android:id="@+id/framelayout"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<com.abc.android.image
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/imageview">
</com.abc.android.image>

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linlayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/small1"
android:orientation="vertical">

  All text view, ImageButtons


</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

can anyone please tell how to use custom-view at background and other components  on a foreground. means components should display over the Custom-view.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code. I have added just two UI widgets i.e a TextView and a Button. You can add more according to you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout01" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/framelayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/imageview01"
        android:background="@drawable/pic">
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearlayout02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView android:text="Text View" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dip" android:textColor="#FF0000" />

        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dip" android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="40dip" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```